# How to enable menu bar for pantheon-terminal

Tags: pantheon-terminal

How to enable menu bar for `pantheon-terminal`?
Is disabled by default in terminal?

*I'd prefer if answers didn't require additional things to be installed.*

Comment: You can also use other terminal apps like Terminator, which have dozen more features

Answer (score 1):

There is no menu bar in Pantheon Terminal.

If you want to change advanced settings you'll to edit dConf values. For more on how to do that [click here](https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/).

I might be able to help you more if you tell me what you want to change.

Comment: Please let me know, Is it a comment or answer?

Comment: Its an answer, there is no menu bar in Pantheon Terminal. You need Gconf or Dconf to edit the settings.

Comment: This is *the* answer. Pantheon Terminal has no menu.

Comment: @RolandiXor "the answer"? then what is it "I  might be able to help you more if you tell me what you want to change."? Asking for clarification or not?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Ravan I meant I might be able to help you setting the Dconf/Gconf settings ;).

Comment: @Jeroen Fair enough :)